# How can I have a local variable that persists over time but is not shared among all members of the same class?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am programming c++ in Unreal Engine. I have some functions that use variables whose value I need to last in time and that are only used within that function. The problem is that if I declare them as static local variables, when I have several members of the same class they all share the same value, and I would like each class to have its own instance of a local variable that lasts over time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you create an example?

Comment: Make a new class that stores these values and recalls them through a function.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to make a member variable of the class. Yes, technically, it will also be available to things outside that member function, but there isn't a way to make a variable at the exact level of sharedness that you want.

Comment: The alternative would be to make the static local variable a `std::map<MyClass *, SomeValueType>` and do insertions and/or lookups into the `std::map` as necessary, using `this` as the key... but that opens the door to dangling pointers, race conditions, re-entrancy problems, and so on, so don't do that, follow Nathan's suggestion instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want that level of encapsulation, you could make a separate `class` for each of your member variables and put the function(s) that operate on that variable in that class. You can then inherit from any number of those separate classes to build a class that has several variables.

Example:

```cpp
struct func_x {
    func_x(int X) : x{X} {}

    int function_using_x() {
        return x;
    }

private:
    int x; // only one member variable
};

struct func_y {
    func_y(int Y) : y{Y} {}

    int function_using_y() {
        return y;
    }
    
private:
    int y; // only one member variable
};


struct foo : func_x, func_y { // inherit from both
    foo(int x, int y) : func_x(x), func_y(y) {}
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    foo f{1, 2};
    std::cout << f.function_using_x() << f.function_using_y() << '\n'; // 12
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you need 2 variables for that.
one for counter (declare local but nut static) and change in one instance and another static for following the first variable;

but notice every time you need that static you should update it

Comment: Can you include some example code showing how that would work?  From the English description alone it's not entirely clear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).